# Recommendation for mysqli batch queries

Tags: php, mysql, batch-processing

**My use case:**

I have multiple scripts inserting into a table in the order of several inserts per second. I am seeing performance degradation, so I think there would be performance benefits in "batching queries" and inserting several hundred rows every minute or so.

**Question:**

How would I go about doing this using mysqli? My current code uses a wrapper ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/a9sQRzyU)), and looks like:

```
$array = array();\\BIG ARRAY OF VALUES (more than 100k rows worth)
foreach($array AS $key => $value){
  $db -> q('INSERT INTO `player_items_attributes` (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 'iii', $value['test1'], $value['test2'], $value['test3']);
}
```

**Notes:**

I looked at using transactions, but it sounds like those would still hit the server, instead of queuing. I would prefer to use a wrapper (feel free to suggest one with similar functionality to what my current one offers), but if not possible I will try to build suggestions into the wrapper I use.

**Sources:**

Wrapper came from [here](http://blog.vjeux.com/2009/php/mysqli-wrapper-short-and-secure-queries.html)

**Edit:**
I am trying optimize table speed, rather than script speed. This table has more than 35million rows, and has a few indexes.

Comment: write a csv file and use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: you can use `DELAYED INSERTS` if your just wanting the PHP script to run faster.

Comment: @Dagon, this is true, but not really using mysqli to any advantage... not to mention it involves writing to disk twice... when RAM is not really a problem. It would definitely be an improvement though over what I currently have.

Comment: @DevZer0 Another good suggestion, but DELAYED INSERTS introduce their own problems, and queuing up thousands and thousands of statements doesn't sound optimal. (Especially as the backlog would probably grow quite fast)

Comment: Maybe I should note that I am trying to optimise table speed, rather than script execution times. The table gets locked for each insert, and while there is no noticeable delay at sub 100k rows, the table is now well above 30million rows large, with a few indexes.

Comment: i wonder if this is the best db\schema\libary for your data , to many variables for me.

Comment: @Dagon
There is no way around it. The data-set is a perpetually growing, and I expect it to be 100m+ rows. Databases are made to hold large data-sets, so the only issue here is: "what is the most efficient way to get the data into the database?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL `INSERT` syntax allows for one `INSERT` query to insert multiple rows, like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

where each set of parenthesised values represents another row in your table. So, by working down the array you could create multiple rows in one query.

There is one major limitation: the total size of the query must not exceed the configured limit. For 100k rows you'd probably have to break this down into blocks of, say, 250 rows, reducing your 100k queries to 400. You might be able to go further.

I'm not going to attempt to code this - you'd have to code something and try it in your environment.

Here's a pseudo-code version:

```
escape entire array // array_walk(), real_escape_string()

block_size = 250; // number of rows to insert per query
current_block = 0;
rows_array = [];


while (next-element <= number of rows) {

    create parenthesised set and push to rows_array  // implode()

    if (current_block == block_size) {
        implode rows_array and append to query 
        execute query
        set current_block = 0
        reset rows_array
        reset query
    }
    current_block++
    next_element++
}

if (there are any records left over) {
    implode rows_array and append to query 
    execute the query for the last block
}
```

I can already think of  a potentially faster implementation with array_map() - try it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reasons you outlined are exactly why I wanted to approach the problem this way. The problem I have though is that mysqli does not seem to "nicely" support doing multiple prepared queries. A pseudo code answer would be lovely, and leave me with something to think about.

Comment: Then don't use a prepared query. Prepared queries are not the silver bullet they're made out to be by some people here. You can always escape the data yourself. If you're balancing 100,000 prepared queries against 400 that you escaped yourself, then I think the argument's fairly clear.

Comment: The argument you put forth is clearly compelling, and I fear that I have fallen for the fallacy that they are the "be all and end all". I was under the (now proven) false assumption that there would supported way to do this. It's annoying that support for this was not built in.

Comment: I'll do something like: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XaV8DEME). I'll accept your answer if no one else provides a nicer mysqli solution by tomorrow.