# PHP timeout error 500

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array with SQL instructions 'TRUNCATE and INSERT', that assembly is retrieved from the txt file.

The procedures truncate and insert are made on 6 tables, the problem is that one of the tables will receive 110,000 records.

I did some tests:

1st http://pastebin.com/egbnbfVa

Phrase ... Error: MySQL server has gone away

Error number 2006 ...

2nd http://pastebin.com/tfF7ZaVd

This ... the 500 error

Comment: Without seeing what the queries are (feel free to sanitize them!) it can be difficult to see what the issues are.  Show us a bit, so we can help you diagnose the problem better.

Comment: Most likely, either PHP or MySQL hit a process time limit (maybe both!) and was killed. Look into either breaking up your SQL operations into smaller pieces, or increasing process time limits.

Comment: Can't you run the source SQL file directly into mysql using the mysql client with the command `source [filename]`?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539742/recommendation-for-mysqli-batch-queries

Answer (score 1):

i think your script is too long to execute. check the php log and change execution_time if you cant optimise your script

Answer (score 1):

Think in this code:

```
<?php
   $configuration = array(
        'mysql-user'    => 'username',
        'mysql-password'    => 'password',
        'mysql-host'    => '127.0.0.1',
        'mysql-database'    => 'database',
   );

   $mysqli = mysqli_connect($configuration["mysql-host"], $configuration["mysql-user"], $configuration["mysql-password"], $configuration["mysql-database"]) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
   $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

and in your 2nd code you have an error

ERROR:

```
for($i=0;i<count($sql_prod_s_saida_inARR);$i++)
```

CORRECT:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($sql_prod_s_saida_inARR); $i++ )
```

One suggestion, if you have 110k of records, made that in parts, for exemple 10k at time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timelimt in the script. YOu can set it to unlimited by using this:

```
set_time_limit ( 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason aswell is that after each insert the table will reindex.
You can stop this with transactions if i'm correct, this will increase your speed with over a 100 times :D